# Django loaddata returns DeserializationError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

I have a json file coming from a dumpdata that I want to load and when doing loaddata after some time it returns this message:

`DeserializationError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'`

There is no clue, no reference, I have no idea where this is coming from. I have tried with Django 1.4.8 and 1.5.4 and the result is the same.

What could it be?

edit: I have added a pdb to find out more and it appears that the objects that trigger the error are from auth.permission.

Comment: Add more details in question, models, sample json that fails etc.

Comment: the objects triggering the error are from auth.permission but I still don't know why.

Comment: @arulmr thanks for such great insight, may I ask more details about what code you would like to see? I run the loaddata command with a json file filled with db objects. I did not write any code to directly execute this action. If you think about a specific part of a Django project that can affect that please tell me and I'll be happy to show you the code.

Comment: Add some sample json data and models code.

Comment: right now the one that fails is not actually in my code, the model is django auth.permission and the actions are related to the django-cms package. I'll keep looking at the objects and post them if I can.

Comment: @Bastian How did you finally fix it? I have the same error. The answer below isn't clear to me. Here is the [link to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933055/deserializationerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-meta-using-django-lo).

Comment: @UnknownCoder I have had to face quite a lot of trouble during this migration so I don't remember exactly the solution to that one in particular. I would say that I had a problem with signals that got executed during import while not all the database was in a stable state yet as it was being imported. It means some signals wanted to execute things on models that were not created yet or something equivalently dirty. Anyway deactivating signals solved my import problem. But you might have signals you actually want to execute in order to retain a stable db so be careful :)

Comment: @UnknownCoder by the way the answer by avenet looks valid in your case. I did not try it but I remember having moved part of the import manually before another part (a dependency of the other part) to make it work. It looks a lot better to set things up cleanly in the models.

Comment: @UnknownCoder I prefer working with the same db at all levels, dev, stage, prod... to avoid that altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem so I don't know if the solution will be the same but here was mine :

I had post_save signals that didn't handle "raw=True" case.

It looks like post_save and pre_save signals are now sent even when you use loaddata, but with a "raw" argument (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture). I don't know if it was already like that before but at least it wasn't in the docs.

So I just put in all my post_save signals :

```
if kwargs['raw']:
    return
```

And it was al fine :)

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this. Saved me from pulling my hair out all night!