# DeserializationError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta' using Django loaddata

Tags: python, mysql, django, json

I am trying to migrate my Django application database from SQLite to MySQl.

I'm dumping the data using `manage.py dumpdata --natural > hunt.json`

Then after updating the settings to connect to a MySQL database, when I `loaddata` using `manage.py loaddata hunt` it throws the following error

```
Problem installing fixture 'hunt.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\loaddata.p
y", line 190, in handle
    for obj in objects:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\json.py", line 47,
 in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError(e)
DeserializationError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Following is my model.py

```
from django.db import models

class DJManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)

class DJ(models.Model):
    objects = DJManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='/img/', height_field=None, width_field=None)
    soundcloud_profile = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def natural_key(self):
    return (self.name,)

    #for human readable representation of objects
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    song_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    normalized_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(DJ, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    artists = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    remixers = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artwork = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genres = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    duplicate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    #for human readable representation of objects
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.normalized_name
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

South was conflicting with the test. I was supposed to set `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False` in `settings.py` as per the [docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-tests-migrate).

> If this is False, South’s test runner integration will make the test
>   database be created using syncdb, rather than via migrations (the
>   default).

Also I was dumping everything into my fixture. This is, apparently, a bad way to do fixtures it with South--because it also dumps the South migration tables into the fixture. So I had to create my fixture to be app-specific
`manage.py dumpdata hunt --natural > hunt.json`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a natural_key() method in your DJ model

```
def natural_key(self):
    return self.name
```

You can check it on the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#dependencies-during-serialization

Comment: Using that gives a `DeserializationError: [u"'Hardwell' value must be an integer."]`

Comment: Okay I was supposed to use `return (self.name,)`because it has to return a tuple, but the `'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'` error still remains.